# IIS 10 - Windows Authentication - AuthenticationType "unavailable"

Tags: windows-authentication

I am a web app that I'm trying to get working with Windows Auth.  However, no matter what I do, I can't get past a 401.

**web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
          <providers>
            <clear />
            <add value="NTLM" />
          </providers>
        </windowsAuthentication>
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
        <clear />
        <add accessType="Deny" users="?" />
        <add accessType="Allow" users="CABLE\mmulhe200" />
      </authorization>
    </security>
    <tracing>
      <traceFailedRequests>
        <add path="*">
          <traceAreas>
            <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket" verbosity="Verbose" />
          </traceAreas>
          <failureDefinitions timeTaken="00:00:00" statusCodes="401.1" />
        </add>
      </traceFailedRequests>
    </tracing>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**IIS Failed Request Trace Output (Partial)**

```
<failedRequest url="http://dev.windowsauthtest.com:80/"
               siteId="3"
               appPoolId="windowsAuthTest"
               processId="33204"
               verb="GET"
               authenticationType="NOT_AVAILABLE"               activityId="{80000727-0003-F400-B63F-84710C7967BB}"
               failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
               statusCode="401.1"
               triggerStatusCode="401.1"
               timeTaken="0"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
               >
```

The part that concerns me is

```
authenticationType="NOT_AVAILABLE"
```

I get prompted to enter my credentials and I enter my NT username/password and it just keeps re-prompting.

Any ideas?

Comment: Although you're not mentioning it, I assume WindowsAuthentication is set as an available authentication method in your IIS?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the Windows Auth feature and it is present in IIS.